# Program not reading from Binary file

Tags: c++, class, binaryfiles

I'm trying to create a test program for a project that I'm doing in school.
One important aspect of my project is to have a login system. 
In `int main()` I have a menu which calls `login();` or `createAccount();` based on the users choice. `login();` further calls `loginToken();` to generate `int authToken` with value `0` or `1`. It calls `loginAuth()` which in turn checks the value of `authToken` and authenticates the login.
In `int main();` when I call `createAccount()` it writes the the vales or `newUsername` and `newPassword` into a binary file `accounts.bin`. However, when I call `login()` the `if` condition I made to check whether `loginEntry` is open says that it is closed, even though I just opened it the line before.

I'd appreciate some help because this has been bothering me for days.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

class Account{
  private:

    char enteredUsername[20];
    char enteredPassword[20];
    int authToken;
    char newUsername[20]; 
    char newPassword[20];
    ofstream loginDetails;
    ifstream loginEntry;

  public:   
    void login(){ // to enter username or password
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');  //to clear cin buffer

        loginEntry.open("account.bin", ios::in|ios::binary); // to read newUsername and newPassword
            if (!loginDetails.is_open()) {  //to check whether file is open or not
            cout<<"File not open";
            }
            else {
                loginEntry.read(newUsername,sizeof(newUsername));
                loginEntry.read(newPassword,sizeof(newPassword));
            }
          loginEntry.close();

        cout<<"\nEnter Username: ";
        cin.getline(enteredUsername, sizeof(enteredUsername));
        cout<<"\nEnter Password: ";
        cin.getline(enteredPassword, sizeof(enteredPassword));
        loginToken(); 
    }
    void loginToken(){ // to generate login token if enteredUsername and enteredPassword match newUsername and newPassword in account.bin 

        if(strcmp(enteredUsername,"user")==0 && strcmp(enteredPassword,"admin")==0)
            authToken=1;

        else
            authToken=0;

        loginAuth(); // to check value of login token and allow or deny access
    }
    void loginAuth(){ 
        if(authToken==1)
            cout<<"Login succesfull!!";
        else
            cout<<"Login Failed. Returning to Menu";

        getchar();
    }
    void createAccount(){  // to create newUsername and newPassword which are saved in account.bin
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');    //to clear cin buffer

        cout<<"\nEnter new Username: "; 
        cin.getline(newUsername,sizeof(newUsername));
        cout<<"\nEnter new Password: ";
        cin.getline(newPassword,sizeof(newPassword)); 

        loginDetails.open("account.bin", ios::out|ios::binary); //writing in account.bin

            loginDetails.write(newUsername, sizeof(enteredUsername));
            loginDetails.write(newPassword, sizeof(enteredPassword));

        loginDetails.close();
        cout<<"\nYour account has been created. Returning to Menu";
        getchar();
    }
}; 

int main(){
Account test;
int userChoice;

do{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Welcome to xyz.com";
    cout<<"\n*Press 1 to Login\n*Not a memeber? Press 2 to create an account and be awesome!!\n*If you're tired, press 3 to leave "<<endl;  
    cin>>userChoice;

    switch(userChoice){
        case 1:{
            test.login();
            break;          
        }
        case 2:{
            test.createAccount();
            break;
        }
    }
}while(userChoice!=3);

cout<<"GoodBye!! :)";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is morphing the problem description and source code instead of just accepting a valid answer to his/her original question.

Comment: I'll accept the answer, should I ask this as another question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In login() you have:

```
loginEntry.open("account.bin", ios::in|ios::binary);
```

And then you have

```
if (!loginDetails.is_open()) {
```

You have opened "entry", not "details", but you are checking "details", which is why it says the error.

## EDIT

There are 2 new potential problems I can see.

In createAccount(), the second parameter sizeof() is returning a size of 0 because enteredUsername and enteredPassword hasn't been used in your method, writing nothing to the file. You probably meant to use newUsername and newPassword instead.

```
loginDetails.write(newUsername, sizeof(enteredUsername));
loginDetails.write(newPassword, sizeof(enteredPassword));
```

In loginToken() you use constants like 'user', instead of the variables you just created in login() called newUsername. Furthermore,

```
loginEntry.read(newUsername,sizeof(newUsername)); //unused
loginEntry.read(newPassword,sizeof(newPassword)); //unused
if(strcmp(enteredUsername,"user")==0 && strcmp(enteredPassword,"admin")==0)
```

Finally, you are using *getLine* in your code, which means you might be reading the \n character at the end of input.

```
cin.getline(enteredUsername, sizeof(enteredUsername));
```

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much. But now I have another problem. I create an account via `createAccount();` . But when I call `login();` to login, it says Login failed. Any help? I'll edit the question accordingly

Comment: @AhmadZafar - this contributor answered your original question. That's it - you should accept it now.  Changing the question so as to invalidate answers is very annoying and unfriendly.

Comment: I think it's fine in this case, since I'm the only one that answered :)

Comment: Aghhh. Silly me, I used that to check the running of the program before implementing files into the source code. Forgot to change it back. Thank you very much for your time :)